# SQL Query for putting highest counters of two tables in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @A table (
name varchar(10)
)



declare @B table (
name varchar(10)
)


insert into @A(name) values('A')
insert into @A(name) values('A')
insert into @A(name) values('A')
insert into @A(name) values('B')
insert into @A(name) values('B')
insert into @A(name) values('B')
insert into @A(name) values('B')



insert into @B(name) values('B')
insert into @B(name) values('B')
insert into @B(name) values('B')
insert into @B(name) values('B')
insert into @B(name) values('B')
insert into @B(name) values('B')
insert into @B(name) values('B')
insert into @B(name) values('A')
insert into @B(name) values('A')
```

@A has 3A's and 4B's

@B has 2A's and 7B's

u can say that

```
           @A      @B
A         3          2

B          4          7
```

deal is we have to get highest numbers into one table.

like 3A's of @A and 7B's of @B should be in one table.

@C should contain

## @C

```
A
A
A
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
```

i wanted to have the content of A's from @A and B's from @B into the table @C.
how?

if possible give me an optimal sql Query for the above example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New answer, now the requirement has been clarified:

```
;With x as (
    Select
      name,
      row_number() over (partition by name order by name) rn
    From
      @A
    Union
    Select
      name,
      row_number() over (partition by name order by name)
    From 
      @B
) 
Insert Into
    @C
Select
    name
From
    x
```

**<kbd>[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/21039)</kbd>**

Previous answer:

```
Select
    name,
    max(c)
From (
    Select
        name,
        count(*) c
    From
        @A
    Group By
        name
    union all
    Select
        name,
        count(*)
    From
        @B
    Group By
        name
    ) x
Group By
    name
```

**<kbd>[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/20789)</kbd>**

Comment: @gyane . . . This appears to answer your question.  If so, you should accept it as an answer.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff , i wanted to have the content of A's from @ A and B's from @ B into the table  @ C. I have mentioned it clearly before, now i have given you the output too. Thank you.

Comment: The just added suggestion is basically what was on my mind too, only I think you don't need `row_number` at all.

Comment: @AndriyM Click on the fiddle link, try it out and report back.

Comment: @Laurence ,  thats easy and simple way to write it down,this is much useful to me , while i wanted to ask if this Query is the most optimized Query achievable on SQL server 2012?

Comment: @gyane That's way to open ended. On the surface this looks like a poor way to store what is essentially `category, name, count`. However, if you have an index on the name column in both tables (which you can't do with table variables) then the query uses a very efficient merge join.

Answer (score 1):

If the actual datasets that you need to work with indeed have just one column, I believe [@Laurence's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18813654/297408) should perfectly suffice.

However, if they have other columns that need to be returned too and those columns do not have the same data like those you've shown us, you could try this approach:

1. Count rows per `name` partition in each table.
2. Combine (`UNION ALL`) the two sets and get the maximum count value per `name` partition in the combined row set.
3. Get the rows where the count value matches the maximum one.

Here's one implementation of the above:

```
WITH counted AS (
  SELECT *, cnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name)
  FROM A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *, cnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name)
  FROM B
),
compared AS (
  SELECT *, maxcnt = MAX(cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY name)
  FROM counted
)
SELECT name, data
FROM compared
WHERE cnt = maxcnt
;
```

You can take a look at [this SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c0cd/1) too.

Comment: Thank you @Andriy M , this is much useful to me , while i wanted to ask if this Query is the most optimized Query achievable on SQL server 2012?

Answer (score 0):

Can't say what do you want to get. If you want to get 3 and 7 in one table - then go with Laurence answer, if you want table you give in question as output, use this:

```
;with cte(name, A, B) as (
    select name, name, cast(null as varchar(10)) from @A
    union all
    select name, cast(null as varchar(10)), name from @B
)
select
    name,
    count(A) as [@A],
    count(B) as [@B]
from cte
group by name
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/20794)</kbd>**